# Set user permissions on each module in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I would like to set user permissions on each module.
Each module would have its table with the permissions. What is the most recommended way to do this?

Reason: My application has some optional modules for only a few clients.

**UPDATE**
Something like:

Table: `mod_inventory_permission`

```
id int
User_id int
Read_permission boolean
Write_permission boolean
Admin_permission boolean
```

Comment: _Each module would have its table with the permissions_ is that something you're stuck with or part of your approach?

Comment: I wonder if it's a good alternative? And how would I do this control in the module?

Comment: checkout [yii2 admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin) module. it can restrict your modules (building access rules, and assiging them to each user or user roles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using Rbac which facilitate you to restrict user in same application to limited modules,controllers, or actions
You have to follow the following step i hope it will help you.
I suggest you to use the auth_ tables provided by yii2 for rbac
**step 1:** import all auth tables 
**step 2:** Create different roles in auth_item tables with type = 1 and all permission with type = 2
**Note** 
Please make sure you enter your permission in some specific pattern,i am using **module/controller/action**,
its up to you how you are going to implement it.
**step 3:** Create generic controller and extend all of your controller from this generic controller,
In your generic controller you have to check whether the user is allow to access the module,controller or action he/she want to access of not.

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
        $module = Yii::$app->controller->module->id;
        $controller = ucfirst(Yii::$app->controller->id);
        $action = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
        if (Yii::$app->user->can($module)) {

            if (Yii::$app->user->can($module . '/' . $controller)) {
                return true;
            } 
            if (Yii::$app->user->can($module . '/' . $controller . '/' . $action)) {
                return true;
            } 
else {
                throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'You are not allowed to view this page');
            }
        } else {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'You are not allowed to view this page');
        }
    }
```

The beforeAction function implement 3 layer authentication you can change it according to your requirements....
i hope it will help you

Comment: I liked the idea, I'll study about this solution. thank you all!

Comment: i also implement it after alot of study it will help you in debugging because you don't have to check it in each controller and actions

Answer (score 1):

You can use RBAC for it! you can set different modules in it and different permission for each module.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've never used RBAC.
Could I use it on all clients? (Which may or may not have the inventory module for example)

Comment: Inside the same application you can do whatever you want and however you want. to restrict user from doing specific actions, modules, controllers inside modules etc.